# Magento2, How to pass product data as query string in Url using JSON template? Custom Module

Tags: magento-2.1, sku, json, url-key, querystring

I am trying to get product name, product SKU, Quantity in Url such that when I write 1 in Url 1-50 products should display, when writing 2 as page number 51-100 products should display. And data goes using JSON template. Also, I need to pass a key in Url.

I have retrieved required data as in Block using classes:

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository
```

As

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPageSize(10); // fetching only 3 products
    return $collection;
}
public function getStockItem($productId)
{
    return $this->_stockItemRepository->get($productId);
}
```

And in template for seeing data validness:

```
$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
  //print_r($product->getData());
  echo 'Product ID:'.$product->getId();
  echo "<br>";
  echo 'Product Name:'.$product->getName();
  echo "<br>";
  echo 'Product SKU:'.$product->getSku();
  echo "<br>";
  //echo 'Product Qty:'.$product->getQty();
  $id = $product->getId();
  $_productStock = $block->getStockItem($id);
  echo 'Product Qty:'.$_productStock->getQty(); echo '<br />';
}
```

This is my JSON template:

```
{

“items”:

            [

                            {“itemID”: “1000”,”name”:”product name 1” },

                            {“itemID”: “1001”,”name”:”product name 2” },

                            etc

            ]



}
```

Like here is an example Url:

```
http://dummy.uk/pointsale?lastoid=15404
```

when I give page number 1, above mention data of products from 1-50 should be displayed.

Here is a tutorial that explains about Order data, but is not working for me.
https://www.human-element.com/order-data-json-custom-route-magento-2/
what should be done to achieve the result?

Comment: Can you please explain more in clear way?

Comment: I have added some more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Thanks for help. I got my solution by this:

```
$cusCollection = array(); 
    $i=0;
    $productCollection = $this->order->getProductCollection();
    foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
        $cusCollection['items'][$i]['itemID'] = $product->getId();
        $id = $product->getId();
        $_productStock = $this->order->getStockItem($id); 
        $productQty = $_productStock->getQty();
        $cusCollection['items'][$i]['name '] = $product->getName().' '.$productQty; 
        $cusCollection['items'][$i]['sku '] = $product->getSku();
        $i++;
}
        echo json_encode($cusCollection);
```

and adding this in collection:

```
$page = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page');
$collection->setPageSize(50)->setCurPage($page);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's multi-dimentional array. If you want to access itemID, name etc., then you need to add foreach of **$productColllection['items']**. Like this below code :

```
foreach ($productCollection['items'] as $product) {
  //print_r($product->getData());
  echo 'Product ID:'.$product->getId();
  echo "<br>";
  echo 'Product Name:'.$product->getName();
  echo "<br>";
  echo 'Product SKU:'.$product->getSku();
  echo "<br>";
  //echo 'Product Qty:'.$product->getQty();
  $id = $product->getId();
  $_productStock = $block->getStockItem($id);
  echo 'Product Qty:'.$_productStock->getQty(); echo '<br />';
}
```

---

**EDIT :**

I don't know about from you access url. But, if you want to add query string into product url then you can add query string like this below way.

```
<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl().'?id=id&name=name' ?>
```

Comment: right, but my actual concern is about passing this gata into URL as query string, can you tell about it.

Comment: I am accessing it via Controller like in example tutorial in question.